# Rolling over Traditional IRA and timing

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, account-transfer

I have a 401k at work. I also have a Traditional IRA.

Both have losses. However, the 401k at work has much fees and expenses. Also it has larger pool of funds to choose from.

I want to consolidate this Traditional IRA into 401k.

Are there considerations regarding timing? i.e. Consolidate now, December 2018, or consolidate in January 2019?

Comment: You just wrote that the 401(k) account has “much fees and expenses. “ Is this a typo?

Comment: Will your employers 401K allow this? Some don't allow you to roll in IRAs

Comment: Once upon a time. a standard Traditional IRA could not be rolled over into a 401(k) (or 403(b)) plan; but IRAs that held funds rolled _into_ them from a 401(k) or 403(b) plan (these were called Rollover IRAs) could be further rolled over into another 401(k) or 403(b) plan _if the plan allowed for such rollovers._ Making a _contribution_ to a Rollover IRA or transferring (non-Rollover) IRA money into a Rollover IRA was called a _commingling_ of funds that changed the entire  Rollover IRA into a Traditional IRA, meaning that _all_ that money could never be rolled over into a 401(k)/403(b) plan.

Answer (score 5):

Both accounts are tax-deferred, so there should be no practical difference (from a tax perspective) when you roll.

That said, I would consider shopping around for a different Traditional IRA broker. Typically, corporate 401(k)s have higher fees and expenses than low-cost brokers that have MANY more investments to choose from. If you can find a broker with better rates AND options, then I would just move your IRA to that and NOT roll it into your 401(k).  Once you leave your job, roll that 401(k) into your new IRA.